# When api endpoint is not available, page crashes

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Working on a svelte-kit app and using 3rd party api.

When api endpoint is not available, try catch block will catch error and at this point I have option to redirect or to send back error and status. In case of sending the error like 404 than template __error.svelte needs to be there if I want to show something other than  plain 404 generic error page.

Example from todo demo from sveltekit init: If todos endpoint not available instead of props we return {status:404, error: 'Not Found'}.

```js
<script context="module" lang="ts">
    import { enhance } from '$lib/form';
    import type { Load } from '@sveltejs/kit';

    export const load: Load = async ({ fetch }) => {
        try {

            const res = await fetch('/notavailable.json');


            if (res.ok) {
                const todos = await res.json();

                return {
                    props: { todos }
                };
            }


        } catch (error) {

                return {
                    status: 404,
                    error: "Page Not Found"
                };
            
        }

    };
</script>
<h1>Current Page</h2>
```

How do I return error message but still load current page? (not redirect or nested templates fallback but rather stay on the page ?)

In case I have a table list I expect only header to be present and message would be in the designated area of the app.

It seams I am missing something or redirects and __error.svelte nested templates is the way to go?

Comment: I could probably solve this with server endpoints and handle on server what I send to client if node adapter is used. What if I have static adapater amd no ssr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an error in my __error.svelte template that I accidentally left behind  ... in the process I figured out how to pass error to page and not redirect to error template.

It was actually very simple:

- if you want to trigger default error handler (__error.svelte) than return error and status like I did in the question above.
- if you still want to proceed to page and handle error message in the page rather than return props and pass the error as a prop to the component instance:

```js
    <script context="module" lang="ts">
        import { enhance } from '$lib/form';
        import type { Load } from '@sveltejs/kit';
    
        export const load: Load = async ({ fetch }) => {
            try {
    
                const res = await fetch('/notavailable.json');
    
    
                if (res.ok) {
                    const todos = await res.json();
    
                    return {
                        props: { todos }
                    };
                }
    
    
            } catch (error) {
    
                    return {
                        props: {
                            todos:[],
                            error: {
                                status: 404,
                                error: "Page Not Found"
                            }
                        }
                    };
                
            }
    
        };
    </script>
```